# Error while executing and initializing kubeadm

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube, kubernetes-health-check

While initializing `kubeadm` I am getting following errors. I have also tried command `kubeadm reset` before doing `kubadm init`. Kubelet is also running and command I have used for same is `systemctl enable kubelet && systemctl start kubelet`. Following is log after executing kubeadm init

```js
[kubeadm] WARNING: kubeadm is in beta, please do not use it for production clusters.
[init] Using Kubernetes version: v1.8.2
[init] Using Authorization modes: [Node RBAC]
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks
[preflight] WARNING: Connection to "https://192.168.78.48:6443" uses proxy "http://user:pwd@192.168.78.15:3128/". If that is not intended, adjust your proxy settings
[preflight] WARNING: Running with swap on is not supported. Please disable swap or set kubelet's --fail-swap-on flag to false.
[preflight] Starting the kubelet service
[kubeadm] WARNING: starting in 1.8, tokens expire after 24 hours by default (if you require a non-expiring token use --token-ttl 0)
[certificates] Generated ca certificate and key.
[certificates] Generated apiserver certificate and key.
[certificates] apiserver serving cert is signed for DNS names [steller.india.com kubernetes kubernetes.default kubernetes.default.svc kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local] and IPs [10.96.0.1 192.168.140.48]
[certificates] Generated apiserver-kubelet-client certificate and key.
[certificates] Generated sa key and public key.
[certificates] Generated front-proxy-ca certificate and key.
[certificates] Generated front-proxy-client certificate and key.
[certificates] Valid certificates and keys now exist in "/etc/kubernetes/pki"
[kubeconfig] Wrote KubeConfig file to disk: "admin.conf"
[kubeconfig] Wrote KubeConfig file to disk: "kubelet.conf"
[kubeconfig] Wrote KubeConfig file to disk: "controller-manager.conf"
[kubeconfig] Wrote KubeConfig file to disk: "scheduler.conf"
[controlplane] Wrote Static Pod manifest for component kube-apiserver to "/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml"
[controlplane] Wrote Static Pod manifest for component kube-controller-manager to "/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-controller-manager.yaml"
[controlplane] Wrote Static Pod manifest for component kube-scheduler to "/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-scheduler.yaml"
[etcd] Wrote Static Pod manifest for a local etcd instance to "/etc/kubernetes/manifests/etcd.yaml"
[init] Waiting for the kubelet to boot up the control plane as Static Pods from directory "/etc/kubernetes/manifests"
[init] This often takes around a minute; or longer if the control plane images have to be pulled.
[kubelet-check] It seems like the kubelet isn't running or healthy.
[kubelet-check] The HTTP call equal to 'curl -sSL http://localhost:10255/healthz' failed with error: Get http://localhost:10255/healthz: dial tcp [::1]:10255: getsockopt: connection refused.
[kubelet-check] It seems like the kubelet isn't running or healthy.
[kubelet-check] The HTTP call equal to 'curl -sSL http://localhost:10255/healthz' failed with error: Get http://localhost:10255/healthz: dial tcp [::1]:10255: getsockopt: connection refused.
[kubelet-check] It seems like the kubelet isn't running or healthy.
[kubelet-check] The HTTP call equal to 'curl -sSL http://localhost:10255/healthz' failed with error: Get http://localhost:10255/healthz: dial tcp [::1]:10255: getsockopt: connection refused.
[kubelet-check] It seems like the kubelet isn't running or healthy.
[kubelet-check] The HTTP call equal to 'curl -sSL http://localhost:10255/healthz/syncloop' failed with error: Get http://localhost:10255/healthz/syncloop: dial tcp [::1]:10255: getsockopt: connection refused.
[kubelet-check] It seems like the kubelet isn't running or healthy.
[kubelet-check] The HTTP call equal to 'curl -sSL http://localhost:10255/healthz/syncloop' failed with error: Get http://localhost:10255/healthz/syncloop: dial tcp [::1]:10255: getsockopt: connection refused.
```

Following is output of `journalctl -u kubelet`

```js
-- Logs begin at Thu 2017-11-02 16:20:50 IST, end at Fri 2017-11-03 17:11:12 IST. --
Nov 03 16:36:48 steller.india.com systemd[1]: Started kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent.
Nov 03 16:36:48 steller.india.com systemd[1]: Starting kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent...
Nov 03 16:36:48 steller.india.com kubelet[52511]: I1103 16:36:48.998467   52511 feature_gate.go:156] feature gates: map[]
Nov 03 16:36:48 steller.india.com kubelet[52511]: I1103 16:36:48.998532   52511 controller.go:114] kubelet config controller: starting controller
Nov 03 16:36:48 steller.india.com kubelet[52511]: I1103 16:36:48.998536   52511 controller.go:118] kubelet config controller: validating combination of defaults and flag
Nov 03 16:36:49 steller.india.com kubelet[52511]: I1103 16:36:49.837248   52511 client.go:75] Connecting to docker on unix:///var/run/docker.sock
Nov 03 16:36:49 steller.india.com kubelet[52511]: I1103 16:36:49.837282   52511 client.go:95] Start docker client with request timeout=2m0s
Nov 03 16:36:49 steller.india.com kubelet[52511]: W1103 16:36:49.839719   52511 cni.go:196] Unable to update cni config: No networks found in /etc/cni/net.d
Nov 03 16:36:49 steller.india.com systemd[1]: kubelet.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 03 16:36:49 steller.india.com kubelet[52511]: I1103 16:36:49.846959   52511 feature_gate.go:156] feature gates: map[]
Nov 03 16:36:49 steller.india.com kubelet[52511]: W1103 16:36:49.847216   52511 server.go:289] --cloud-provider=auto-detect is deprecated. The desired cloud provider sho
Nov 03 16:36:49 steller.india.com kubelet[52511]: error: failed to run Kubelet: unable to load bootstrap kubeconfig: stat /etc/kubernetes/bootstrap-kubelet.conf: no such
Nov 03 16:36:49 steller.india.com systemd[1]: Unit kubelet.service entered failed state.
Nov 03 16:36:49 steller.india.com systemd[1]: kubelet.service failed.
Nov 03 16:37:00 steller.india.com systemd[1]: kubelet.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Nov 03 16:37:00 steller.india.com systemd[1]: Started kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent.
Nov 03 16:37:00 steller.india.com systemd[1]: Starting kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent...
Nov 03 16:37:00 steller.india.com kubelet[52975]: I1103 16:37:00.134702   52975 feature_gate.go:156] feature gates: map[]
Nov 03 16:37:00 steller.india.com kubelet[52975]: I1103 16:37:00.134763   52975 controller.go:114] kubelet config controller: starting controller
Nov 03 16:37:00 steller.india.com kubelet[52975]: I1103 16:37:00.134767   52975 controller.go:118] kubelet config controller: validating combination of defaults and flag
Nov 03 16:37:00 steller.india.com kubelet[52975]: I1103 16:37:00.141273   52975 client.go:75] Connecting to docker on unix:///var/run/docker.sock
Nov 03 16:37:00 steller.india.com kubelet[52975]: I1103 16:37:00.141364   52975 client.go:95] Start docker client with request timeout=2m0s
Nov 03 16:37:00 steller.india.com kubelet[52975]: W1103 16:37:00.143023   52975 cni.go:196] Unable to update cni config: No networks found in /etc/cni/net.d
Nov 03 16:37:00 steller.india.com kubelet[52975]: I1103 16:37:00.149537   52975 feature_gate.go:156] feature gates: map[]
Nov 03 16:37:00 steller.india.com kubelet[52975]: W1103 16:37:00.149780   52975 server.go:289] --cloud-provider=auto-detect is deprecated. The desired cloud provider sho
Nov 03 16:37:00 steller.india.com kubelet[52975]: I1103 16:37:00.179873   52975 certificate_manager.go:361] Requesting new certificate.
Nov 03 16:37:00 steller.india.com kubelet[52975]: E1103 16:37:00.180392   52975 certificate_manager.go:284] Failed while requesting a signed certificate from the master:
Nov 03 16:37:00 steller.india.com kubelet[52975]: I1103 16:37:00.181404   52975 manager.go:149] cAdvisor running in container: "/sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct/system.slice/k
Nov 03 16:37:00 steller.india.com kubelet[52975]: W1103 16:37:00.223876   52975 manager.go:157] unable to connect to Rkt api service: rkt: cannot tcp Dial rkt api servic
Nov 03 16:37:00 steller.india.com kubelet[52975]: W1103 16:37:00.224005   52975 manager.go:166] unable to connect to CRI-O api service: Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fcrio.so
Nov 03 16:37:00 steller.india.com kubelet[52975]: I1103 16:37:00.262573   52975 fs.go:139] Filesystem UUIDs: map[17856e0b-777f-4065-ac97-fb75d7a1e197:/dev/dm-1 2dc6a878-
Nov 03 16:37:00 steller.india.com kubelet[52975]: I1103 16:37:00.262604   52975 fs.go:140] Filesystem partitions: map[/dev/sdb:{mountpoint:/D major:8 minor:16 fsType:xfs
Nov 03 16:37:00 steller.india.com kubelet[52975]: I1103 16:37:00.268969   52975 manager.go:216] Machine: {NumCores:56 CpuFrequency:2600000 MemoryCapacity:540743667712 Hu
Nov 03 16:37:00 steller.india.com kubelet[52975]: 967295 Mtu:1500} {Name:eno49 MacAddress:14:02:ec:82:57:30 Speed:10000 Mtu:1500} {Name:eno50 MacAddress:14:02:ec:82:57:3
Nov 03 16:37:00 steller.india.com kubelet[52975]: evel:1} {Size:262144 Type:Unified Level:2}]} {Id:13 Threads:[12 40] Caches:[{Size:32768 Type:Data Level:1} {Size:32768
Nov 03 16:37:00 steller.india.com kubelet[52975]: s:[26 54] Caches:[{Size:32768 Type:Data Level:1} {Size:32768 Type:Instruction Level:1} {Size:262144 Type:Unified Level:
Nov 03 16:37:00 steller.india.com kubelet[52975]: I1103 16:37:00.270145   52975 manager.go:222] Version: {KernelVersion:3.10.0-229.14.1.el7.x86_64 ContainerOsVersion:Cen
Nov 03 16:37:00 steller.india.com kubelet[52975]: I1103 16:37:00.271263   52975 server.go:422] --cgroups-per-qos enabled, but --cgroup-root was not specified.  defaultin
Nov 03 16:37:00 steller.india.com kubelet[52975]: error: failed to run Kubelet: Running with swap on is not supported, please disable swap! or set --fail-swap-on flag to
Nov 03 16:37:00 steller.india.com systemd[1]: kubelet.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 03 16:37:00 steller.india.com systemd[1]: Unit kubelet.service entered failed state.
Nov 03 16:37:00 steller.india.com systemd[1]: kubelet.service failed.
```

Comment: Can you share output of journalctl -u kubelet ?

Comment: kuberentes started to support swap on since 1.22. It will be beta in 1.23. Currently, it's alpha feature.
See https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/issues/2400 for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have enabled swap on your server, can you disable it and re-run the init command.

```
error: failed to run Kubelet: Running with swap on is not supported, please disable swap! or set --fail-swap-on flag to
```

Here is the steps to disable swap in centos https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-swap-removing.html

Comment: Hi, i have set flag `--fail-swap-on` to `false`, but now i am getting following error : `Nov 06 11:57:45 steller.india.com kubelet[24572]: error: failed to run Kubelet: failed to create kubelet: misconfiguration: kubelet cgroup driver: "systemd" is differen`

Comment: You need match the docker and kubelet cgroup driver.

Comment: check docker cgroup driver like this `docker info |grep -i cgroup`. then change it to kubelet one. `sed -i 's#Environment="KUBELET_CGROUP_ARGS=--cgroup-driver=systemd"#Environment="KUBELET_CGROUP_ARGS=--cgroup-driver=cgroupfs"#g' /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf`. then restart kubelet

Answer (score 21):

just disable the swap in the machine. **sudo swapoff -a**

Comment: `swapoff -a && sed -i '/swap/d' /etc/fstab` centos

Comment: What are the side effects of doing this?

Answer (score 15):

## Some Kubernetes Deployments Need Swap

Generally speaking, the [**official requirement**](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/#before-you-begin) is to disable swap.

Reason? not yet supported by kubernetes. IMO they ask you to disable swap to prevent issues with **multi-node cluster** workload shifting.

However, I have a valid use case - I'm developing an on-prem product, linux distro, included with kubeadm. no horizontal scaling by design. To survive opportunistic memory peaks and still function (but slow), **I definitely need swap**.

---

### To install `kubeadm` with swap enabled:

1. Create a file in `/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/20-allow-swap.conf` with the content:

   ```
   [Service]
   Environment="KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS=--fail-swap-on=false"
   ```
2. Run

   ```
   sudo systemctl daemon-reload
   ```
3. Initialize `kubeadm` with flag `--ignore-preflight-errors=Swap`

   ```
   kubeadm init --ignore-preflight-errors=Swap
   ```

Comment: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/53533?fbclid=IwAR3gNXuemHUFnTZe0qtibr5UaHN19VX1tTtvDgoXdIzJWzVtMY1V56QIKy4#issuecomment-637715138

Comment: Just a note, Kubernetes now has alpha support for Swap - https://kubernetes.io/blog/2021/08/09/run-nodes-with-swap-alpha/

Answer (score 3):

sudo swapoff -a   is not persistent across reboot.

You may disable swap after reboot by just commenting out (add # in front of the line) the swap entry in /etc/fstab file. It will prevent swap partition from automatically mounting after a reboot.

Steps:

1. Open the file /etc/fstab
2. Look for a line below

   # swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation

   UUID=e7bf7d6e-e90d-4a96-91db-7d5f282f9363 none            swap    sw              0       0
3. Comment out above line with # and save it. It should look like below

   # swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation

   #UUID=e7bf7d6e-e90d-4a96-91db-7d5f282f9363 none            swap    sw              0       0
4. Reboot the system or for current session execute "sudo swapoff -a" to avoid reboot.

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu disable SWAP and make it persistent:

`sudo swapoff -a && sudo sed -i '/swap/d' /etc/fstab`

Second command will disable SWAP permanently by commenting out SWAP row in file **/etc/fstab**

Answer (score 0):

I'll guess different users will reach this question for different reasons so I'll add additional explanation here.

The fastest and safest solution is to disable swap - like mentioned in link which @Jossef_Harush shared, this is also recommended by K8S. 
 But as he also mentioned - some workloads require more in-depth memory management.

**If you encounter the mentioned error because swap was enabled by purpose** -
I would suggest reading about [Evicting end-user Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/out-of-resource/#evicting-end-user-pods) before considering enabling swap:

> If the kubelet is unable to reclaim sufficient resource on the node,
> kubelet begins evicting Pods.
>
> The kubelet ranks Pods for eviction first by whether or not their
> usage of the starved resource exceeds requests, then by Priority, and
> then by the consumption of the starved compute resource relative to
> the Pods' scheduling requests.
>
> As a result, kubelet ranks and evicts Pods in the following order:
>
> - BestEffort or Burstable Pods whose usage of a starved resource exceeds its request. Such pods are ranked by Priority, and then usage
>   above request.
> - Guaranteed pods and Burstable pods whose usage is beneath requests are evicted last. Guaranteed Pods are guaranteed only when requests
>   and limits are specified for all the containers and they are equal.
>   Such pods are guaranteed to never be evicted because of another Pod's
>   resource consumption. If a system daemon (such as kubelet, docker, and
>   journald) is consuming more resources than were reserved via
>   system-reserved or kube-reserved allocations, and the node only has
>   Guaranteed or Burstable Pods using less than requests remaining, then
>   the node must choose to evict such a Pod in order to preserve node
>   stability and to limit the impact of the unexpected consumption to
>   other Pods. In this case, it will choose to evict pods of Lowest
>   Priority first.

Make sure you're also familiar with:

1 ) [The 3 qos classes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/quality-service-pod/#qos-classes) - Make sure that your high priority workloads are running with the Guaranteed (or at least Burstable) class.

2 ) [Pod Priority and Preemption](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/pod-priority-preemption/).